# Celery chord not releasing redis pubsub channel after apply_async

Tags: django, redis, celery

I am starting a `chord` from celery inside my `django` app in response to a request.  The chord executes correctly, but the pub-sub channel is never released by django.   Killing the django server releases the channel and it then disappears from `redis-cli pubsub channels`.

- Celery 4.1.1 or 4.2.0rc4
- Redis 4.0.9
- Python 2.7.15
- Running locally, 1 celery worker, 1 api server
- Results do not matter in this case (but docs say to not ignore them)
- Full example project at: https://github.com/awbacker/celerychord-issue

After hitting `/api/start/` and watching the tasks complete in the tab running celery, I see 5 channels remaining.  Killing django removes the channels, killing the celery worker has no effect on them.

```
redis-cli pubsub channels
1) "celery-task-meta-chord-lphsmq-chunk-4-14"
2) "celery-task-meta-chord-lphsmq-chunk-2-12"
3) "celery-task-meta-chord-lphsmq-chunk-3-13"
4) "celery-task-meta-chord-lphsmq-chunk-1-11"
5) "celery-task-meta-chord-lphsmq-chunk-0-10"
```

I see the channels persist when everything goes right, so no errors are thrown.

Can anyone see something that I am doing wrong?  I know there are a few issues reported in celery, but I am not sure if this follows from them:

- https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3812
- https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4761

Code:

```
# --- endpoint.py -------------------------------------------
chord_key = get_random_string(6, string.ascii_lowercase)
all_tasks = celery.chord(
    task_id="chord-%s" % chord_key,
    header=celery.group(
        tasks.process_chunk.subtask(args=(x,), task_id="chord-%s-chunk-%s-%s" % (chord_key, i, x))
        for i, x in enumerate(range(10, 15))
    ),
    # immutable = ignore results from parent
    body=celery.chain(
        tasks.post_step_1.subtask(args=(20,), task_id="chord-%s-post-1" % chord_key, immutable=True),
        tasks.post_step_2.subtask(args=(20,), task_id="chord-%s-post-1" % chord_key, immutable=True),
    )
)
result = all_tasks.apply_async()
return Response(data=dict(chord_key=chord_key, result=repr(result)))

# --- tasks.py ----------------------------------------------
@celery_app.task(bind=True, ignore_result=False)
def process_chunk(self, x):
    logging.error(" ~ executing process-chunk: %s" % x)
    return x * 2


@celery_app.task(bind=True, ignore_result=False)
def post_step_1(self, y):
    logging.error(" ~ executing post-step-1")
    return y * 3


@celery_app.task(bind=True, ignore_result=False)
def post_step_2(self, z):
    logging.error(" ~ executing post-step-2")
    return z * 5
```

Comment: This looks exactly like the [3808 issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3808), which FWIW is still not fixed in 4.4.0 (using the [3812 example code snippet](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3812).

Answer (score -2):

youre Chord looks very complex, maybe that's why celery is having a hard time, i would suggest to implement to chord logic youreself, it not very complicated.
try this instead ... i am basically waiting for tasks instaed of using the chord mechanism

```
# --- endpoint.py ------------------------------------------- 
chain_tasks = celery.chain(
            tasks.post_step_1.subtask(args=(20,), task_id="chord-%s-post-1" % chord_key, immutable=True),
            tasks.post_step_2.subtask(args=(20,), task_id="chord-%s-post-1" % chord_key, immutable=True)
            .apply_async()
chain_result= chain_tasks.get() // WAIT TO FINISH

group_task = celery.group(tasks.process_chunk.subtask(args=(chain_result,), task_id="chord-%s-chunk-%s-%s" % (chord_key, i, x))
            for i, x in enumerate(range(10, 15)).apply_async()
group_result = group_task.get()
return Response(data=dict(chord_key=chord_key, result=repr(group_result)))
```

not sure if this is exactly what you were trying to achieve but i think that with a few tweaks it will work.
good luck.

Comment: Not sure how I can run the post processing before the _actual_ processing.  Also not sure why I would want to make celery block my view by calling .get() on a task which can take over 20 minutes to complete in some cases.  What you've done is remove the chord completely, which isn't helpful and doesn't address the question.  The chord itself is also basically ripped from the documentation, so I'm really not sure what you mean by "too complex"!